# Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM advance relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Greeting all artisans.

I am finding the best practice to solve the relationships as tables below:

### TABLE "companies"

```
id     name

1      Apple
2      Google
3      Facebook
...
```

### TABLE "staffs"

```
id     name   company_id

1      Alex   1
2      Benny  1
3      Tony   2
...
```

### TABLE "posts"

```
id     content           staff_id

1      Lorem ipsum A     1
2      Lorem ipsum B     1
3      Lorem ipsum C     5
...
```

How can I define relationships with eloquent so that I can select all 'posts' from specific 'company'. I can declare additional 'company_id' column in 'posts' table for workaround.

But can we using eloquent to select as like example:

```
$posts = Post::where('staff_id', IN, COMPANY_ID)->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally Laravel 4.1 provide this feature called `hasManyThrough`! Horray!

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
I seem to have misunderstood the question, you can eager load nested relationships like this:

```
$company = Company::find(COMPANY_ID)->with('staff.posts')->get();
```

then you can loop through them:

```
foreach($company->staff() as $staff)
{
     foreach($staff->posts() as $post)
     {
         echo $post->content;
     }
}
```

Both relationships need to be defined though.

```
// models/company.php
public function staff()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Staff');
}
```

and

```
// models/staff.php
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

Comment: Hi, the issue with the model relation defined as you mentioned didn't work since posts table doesn't have company_id but just staff_id.

Comment: No appologies, I am very glad you look into my issue :) Well, 2nd approach only can get company staffs but not posts belongs to the company...

Comment: thanks, but that is the usual way as from documentation. For my case, I will have views that need to get all posts belongs to a company, solution above not ideal if need to apply sorting of posts. :/